# Node Express proxy getting Status Code: 404 Not Found instead of 200 success code

Tags: node.js, angular, express

My server.js file looks like below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
//const request = require('request');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("access-control-allow-credentials", "true"),
        // res.header("access-control-allow-methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"), 
        res.header("access-control-allow-methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"),

        next();
});

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/myApp'));

app.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));

app.post("/dashboard", cors(corsOptions), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers); // the posted data
    console.log(req.query.module);
    res.sendStatus(200)
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log('Running......'));
```

When i do node server.js and hit http://localhost:3001/ hit in browser i am getting my page what i mentioned a /dashboard in this same file.

But i am getting Status Code: 404 Not Found.
URL is showing in network tab is http://localhost:3001/student/allstudent.

What else i should changes? if start with proxy.conf.json with 4200 port it will work fine. but now i am not starting as a proxy.conf.json because i am starting node server.js. can some help me. should we provide any proxy for express is different than angular node server.

Comment: I think, you have no route for student/allstudent in your express server. Please, make it first and try again.

Comment: I have working the application when i start node server on 4200 for angular and backend with 8080 using proxy. but now i just want to use express to get My Organization single sign on logged in user name through request headers. after getting the user name in app.js file from there i want to work how regular angular application working all routes and everything. for just to get that user name from request and continue with angular as it is how it is working now. for this what changes should we do in app.js and other than that should we do any other changes.

Comment: Can you please let me know whether i have to use like route.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname))); instead of app.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname))); in all places or. i am getting my home page and when i click on some button its hitting correct url but its giving 404.  do  i need to star node server.js as well npm start? or only node server.js is enough?  because if leave express and just npm start working fine with rest api. issue now only to use with express server

Answer (score 0):

This is an example my folder structure:

```js
/**
 * dist
 *   - myApp
 *     - index.html
 * src
 *   index.js
 * package.json
 */
```

In my `index.js` I'm using your code above, but in your `app.get('/*')` I change with this code below :

```js
app.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/myApp', 'index.html')));
```

With the code above , it's working fine.

**Updated: Why You Get Some Error?**

**The reson why you get 404 error** when you send `POST` request is because you're not have any `POST` method in your express server.

‍ So, **for example**, you can add the same route as the one above and don't forget to change the method from `GET` to`POST`.

**Example of the same Route as the `POST` method**

```js
app.post("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/myApp', 'index.html')));
```

So, now you have 1 route that is the same as 2 methods, namely `GET` and`POST`, like as this code below:

```js
// route with GET METHOD
app.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/myApp', 'index.html')));
// route with POST METHOD
app.post("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/myApp', 'index.html')));
```

⏱ **Now, you can try again**, if it works with the `POST` method and you don't need the`GET` method, then you can delete those using the `GET` method.

I hope it's can help.

Comment: when i enter in browser http://localhost:3001/ its going to http://localhost:4200/dashboard this is fine as i have angular routing is defined like that . now i have link on dashboard page and when i click on that i have API call like this.http.post("/api/student/allstudent", jsonObj, headerObj). angular proxy is like below "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    }. actually its working fine when i do ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json. but i want to work same when i do node server.js as i want to work with express server

Comment: I am getting error like below status 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:3001/api/student/allstudent" can't post /api/student/allstudent. what to do to work with express same as regular angular. just i added server.js file and starting as node server.js . only this change i did. if i do ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json it will works perfectly. issue is when i start as node server.js please help me on this as i am completly new to angular and UI

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. After adding the proxy its worked fine. i am able to see my req headers when i click on some link after page loading..but i want to get request headers on page load itself. First time page will load after Single sign on from organization log in page. so i want to get the headers on page load so i can get my user id and based on that i can route to different pages based on the conditions. any idea please help